# How to write to data to copy and paste buffer?

Tags: command-line, bash

How do i write data from the Command-line into the copy paste buffer?
I see the programs xsel, and xclip and they look fine, but i would prefer a command line option. Can i redirect terminal output to the buffer some how? What is the technical name for the copy paste buffer?

I use mate for the desktop environment. The reason I want to be able to do this without installing anything is I want to be able to write scripts to use this function even on systems where i am not an administrator... i know i can compile in my home directory, but i would still prefer a standard output method. I wouldnt mind writing a bit of c-code to do it either.

I am still not certain, perhaps the copy paste buffers are just frame buffers?

Comment: I guess it depends on the virtual terminal application you're running. Do you run gnome-terminal, xterm or something else? Do you use X or is it just the linux console?

Comment: I think I was asking where the copy paste buffer is, not how to do it manually, but programaticly. I'm sure I used expect, and xev to solve it,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To redirect STDOUT to the X11 clipboard, you can pipe it into `xclip`:

```
$  echo -n my example text to STDOUT | xclip -i -selection clipboard
```

You can see what's in the clipboard with:

```
$  xclip -o -selection clipboard
```

See `xclip` man page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (if I understand correctly what you want) is to select the text with your mouse and then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy it into the regular clipboard. From there you use the standard <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste it into any application in your GUI.

To paste copied text from the GUI into the terminal you use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.